# PhpStorm Twig support for a non-symfony project

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, twig, phpstorm

I have inherited a WordPress project that is heavily decoupled from WordPress, and uses twig. I am using PhpStorm and none of the Twig features seem to be working e.g. jumping to variable declarations, autocomplete & namespaces etc.

In a traditional Symfony project, I can see that the Symfony and Twig configuration options and namespaces are all populated and configured automatically, but that is not the case with this project.

Is there some minimum manual configuration that needs to be done in order to get Twig support working in a non-symfony project?

Comment: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/intro.html

Comment: Twig support? AFAIK is enabled by default and it's coming as a plugin from JetBrains itself so I am not sure what are you asking ...

Comment: @ReynierPM In my non-symfony project, the Twig autocomplete/variable declarations features don't work. In a new symfony project they work fine. I want to know why, and what the requirements are to get it working.

The reason I linked the Twig extension to Symfony is that the Twig config options sit under the Symfony config options in my PhpStorm preferences.

Comment: @Brendan I didn't go deeper in the extension but you can contact the developer directly and ask him what to do in this cases. Apparently you're right and the Twig plugin is coupled with the Symfony one - as per in Settings.